# C# ListView with CheckBoxes, automatic checkbox checked when multi select rows

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, checkbox, multi-select

I'm using a ListView control with multirow and fullrow select on.  When I'm selecting multiple rows at once, some of my rows magically become checked.  This happens when dragging the mouse over and also when selecting one, and shift clicking another.

See image describing issue here: [image]

What in the grapefruit is going on?  Anyone?

Comment: Great question!  Very clearly describes the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately there are bugs in the ListView class, this is one of them. The following code is a fix that worked for me.

Edit: Sorry, this doesn't work quite right, although it does prevent the error that you show in your question. This prevents selecting multiple items and then checking them by clicking the check box.

```
void SetupListView()
{
    listView.ItemCheck += new ItemCheckEventHandler(listView_ItemCheck);
    listView.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(listView_MouseDown);
    listView.MouseUp += new MouseEventHandler(listView_MouseUp);
    listView.MouseLeave += new EventHandler(listView_MouseLeave);
}

bool mouseDown = false;
void listView_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    mouseDown = false;
}

void listView_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    mouseDown = false;
}

void listView_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    mouseDown = true;
}

void listView_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
{
    if(mouseDown)
    {
        e.NewValue = e.CurrentValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: To allow the toggling of multiple items by directly clicking the checkbox I simply changed the `mouseDown = true;` to `mouseDown = e.X > 20;`.  This works for me as the CheckBoxes are on the left hand side of the ListView window.

Answer (score 4):

I answered this in another forum:

http://www.codeproject.com/Messages/3417741/Re-how-to-disable-multi-select-of-checkbox-in-list.aspx

HTH - hground

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO.  When your answer is merely a link elsewhere, consider just posting a comment with the link.  For an answer, it helps if you provide at least brief insight into what the link is about.  Still, a good answer!

Comment: Your code in that link solved my problem after so much searching! thanks

Answer (score 2):

it`s simple question
just try this

```
private void listView1_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
{
    if (ModifierKeys == Keys.Control || ModifierKeys == Keys.Shift)
    {
        e.NewValue = e.CurrentValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the best answer in my opinion.
That being said, on my end, I added `|| (ModifierKeys == (Keys.Control | Keys.Shift))` to the predicate in case the user for some reason is pressing both shift+ctl.